# Can you identify this "memory" card game with 3 secret cards, lowest score wins

Tags: identify-this-game

Last summer, my nephew taught our family a card game.  I think he learned it in Singapore.  We would like to find out what the game is called.

**THE RULES - as best as I can remember them:**

Each player is dealt three cards, face down.  He can look at them once, but has to remember the values from then on.

The rest of the cards are put in a drawing pile.  One card is flipped and put in a discard pile.

The players take turns, drawing either the top discard or the top from the drawing pile.  He can swap the card with one of his three face-down cards if he wants to.  Then he discards the extra card in the discard pile, face up.  This swap will allow the player (and others) to refresh their memory of which cards are in which positions.

Face cards are special:

- If you pick up a Jack (from the drawing pile or from the discard pile), you can peek at any face-down card.
- If you pick up a Queen, you can swap any two face-down cards belonging to another player.
- If you pick up a King, you can swap one of your own face-down cards with one of someone else's.

The goal is to minimize the sum of your three face-down cards.  When the draw pile is depleted, everyone flips their face-down cards and adds up the values (A=1, J-11, Q=12, K=13).

You can play many rounds.  Just keep adding the scores from each round.  The lowest score wins.

--

I might have some of the rules wrong.

Please help us identify this game.

Comment: This does sound a bit like the "Switch" variant of Thirty-One https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-one_(card_game)

Answer (score 3):

The rules are very close to [Cabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)). Differences:

## number of cards

- 4 cards face down instead of 3, and the player may look at only two of them at the start of play

## card powers

- Q or J: blind swap
- 9 or 10: peek at another player's card
- 7 or 8: peek at your own card

## scoring

- all cards according to rank (A=1, K=13)

Comment: Wikipedia tells me I have been playing the Swiss variant of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds a lot like [Four card golf](https://www.pagat.com/draw/golf.html#four) though when I played it we did two cards face up, and two face down, so it's totally possible yours is just a regional variation.

Comment: Four card Golf with Power Cards, Yep. Cabo is one of the names for, as that page notes, "Golf with Power Cards"