# Card game possibly called kings

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for the name or instructions for a card game. This is what I've been told but feels like I'm missing something.
Looking for a card game apparently called "kings".

Everyone is dealt 4 cards each and always only has 4 cards in hand at a time.
Can only look at 2 of your cards at the start of each round.
Take turns either taking a card from the top of the deck or from the discard pile but you need to put down a card from your hand.
Idea is to get the lowest score possible. King is worth 0. Ace is 1. Jack, Queens are 10. Joker is 50 and as soon as it is flipped onto the table the round is over.
First to 100 loses.

Round is ended by either the joker being place on the pile or when someone knocks on the table. Everyone else gets one more go after someone knocks. You knock When you think you’ve got a pretty good low score and want to wrap up the round before others have a chance to swap out some of their cards for a lower score.

I've read the rules for kabo but I don't think it's quite the same.

Comment: This is definitely the card game played with a traditional playing card deck that inspired the commercial game [Cabo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabo_(game)). If you look at the French version of the wikipedia page you'll find more complete rules for the traditional game, and it fits exactly.

Comment: See also this related question: [Can you identify this memory card game with secret cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/47867/can-you-identify-this-memory-card-game-with-3-secret-cards-lowest-score-wins/47871#comment86026_47871)

Answer (score 0):

The description of this sounds like a variation of Golf.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf_(card_game)

In Golf, each player has a grid of cards that you replace with cards in a middle pile to try to lower the score of your cards. The scores of the cards you mention line up with Wikipedia's description. Golf has additional rules where pairs in a column cancel out and 2's are worth minus two points.

Golf is usually played with six cards in each player's grid, but there is a four-card variant.